# Cypress - Insert file content in textarea

Tags: javascript, cypress

Can someone assist (if it is possible to be done, at all) in following case:

Have small HTML which has to be inserted into textarea.
Is there any possibility to be added whole content (that HTML is saved as .html file in **/fixtures/files** folder) and not be done in following way:

```
        inputHugeCodeChunk(elementCss) {
          cy.get(elementCss)
            .type(first line of HTML file)
            .type('{shift}{enter}')
            .type(second line of HTML file)
            .type('{shift}{enter}')
            .type(third line of HTML file)
            .type('{shift}{enter}')
            .type(fourth line of HTML file)
            .type('{shift}{enter}')
            ...
```

And HTML looks (just an example, could be any other file type):

```
<div class="row footer">
  <div class="col-md-3 d-none d-md-block">
   <p></p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 footer-content">
  <table class="w-100 t-buttons">
   <tbody>
              <!-- <tr>
                  <td colspan="3">
                      <p class="text-center">Certified Organic Rosehip Oil</p>
                      <div class="line w-100"></div>
                  </td>
      </table>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a break-down of HTML into lines and loop over the lines.

You will probably need to throttle the typing rate to allow the web page to respond to each line.

```js
inputHugeCodeChunk(elementCss, html) {
  const lines = html.split('\n')
  lines.forEach(line => {
    cy.get(elementCss)
      .type(line)
      .type('{shift}{enter}')
      .wait(50)                  // small wait to ensure field is not swamped
  })
}
```

An alternate approach is to replace all the `\n` with `{shift}{enter}`, then you can use the Cypress option `delay` to avoid swamping.

```js
inputHugeCodeChunk(elementCss, html) {
  const lines = html.replace('\n', '{shift}{enter}')
  cy.get(elementCss)
    .type(lines, {delay:20})
}
```

Comment: Alternate approach did the job.
Thank you very much